# Updating textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I've seen this problem asked before, but all the suggestions I've tried as well as some experimentation on my own have failed.

If I run the following code using Javascript, the textarea will display only the last value of i (5).  If I use the alert that is commented out, then it works.

I've tried using timeout, invterval, date and time delays and even loops to delay processing but none works unless I use an alert as used in the code below when not commented out.  I know some delays still allow processing to continue.  I've also tried passing variables to other functions to display in the textarea from there since it appears the textarea displays the last value after exiting the function.

Any suggestions how I can get the textarea to update with each iteration so the numbers 1 through 5 are displayed one at a time?

And I'm curious why the alert will work when other methods of pausing the action won't.

Thanks.

```
function Go(){
  var i = 0;
  for(i=0; i<6; i++){
    alert("This allows textarea to update with each iteration");
    document.getElementById("ta").value = "";
    document.getElementById("ta").value = i;
  }
}

<textarea id="ta" name="display" rows="15" cols="50"></textarea>
<br /><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="START" onClick="Go()">
```

Comment: I believe he wants it to increment, e.g. 1, then 2, then 3 rather than all be appended at once.

Comment: [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/fmsa7/) ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possible example using recursion:

```
function Go(counter){    
    if (counter > 5){
       return;
    } else {
       document.getElementById("ta").value = counter;
       window.setTimeout(function(){ Go(++counter) }, 500);
    }
};

Go(1);
```

If you just passed your function as the callback to a timer, the timer would have waited the specified duration, then executed the function - which runs through all the iterations without any delays between. You have to wait between function calls (or iterations) to see the number increase. Hope that helps :)

Comment: PS: The alert looked like it was working because alerts will freeze the page until they are dismissed

Comment: Thanks.  I was really curious about that one.  I only put the alert in there to find where things were going wrong only to discover that things started going right once I did that and no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using scope and `setTimeout`

```
function Go(){
    var i = 0,
        fn = function () {
            if (i >= 6) return;
            document.getElementById("ta").value = i;
            ++i;
            window.setTimeout(fn, 500);
        };
    fn();
}
```

Comment: hey, that is a closure! :D

Comment: This one does exactly what I wanted, too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some of those other methods actually spawn background threads so that forward processes can continue unabated.  You need something that will pause the run until the specified time is up, or alternatively run as an event-driven mechanism.

`window.setTimeout()` works great for this.  I used jquery to locate the objects, and wait for domready in my example. You're under no obligation to do this, I just find it easier.  [Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/paulprogrammer/PfAk6/2/)

```
$(function() {
    var iterations = 6;

    var burndown = function() {
        var value = $("#fooinput").val() - 1;
        $("#fooinput").val(value);
        if( value > 0) {
            window.setTimeout(burndown,1000);
        } else {
            $("#clickme").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    }

    $("#clickme").click(function() {
        $("#clickme").attr("disabled","true");
        $("#fooinput").val(iterations);
        window.setTimeout(burndown,1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Stick with pure JS if jQuery isn't tagged in the question! :)

Comment: **Editorial:** Actually, I had written off JS before jQuery because I have such a hard time making cross-platform pure JS work.  (I still struggle with cross-platform CSS) I'm a Java programmer that sometimes has to do front-end work.  Feel free to edit out my jquery if you feel so inclined.

Comment: I don't know jQuery, but I'll hang on to this as I plan to dive into CSS.  I learned HTML decades ago.  A lot has changed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the numbers one at a time, use a simple interval function, then clear it when you're done:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var textArea = document.getElementById("ta");
    var currentVal = textArea.value || -1;

    currentVal == 5 ? clearInterval(interval) : textArea.value = ++currentVal;
}, 2000);
```

And your onClick: `onClick="interval">`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/at4aX/

Comment: Does exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Thanks for all your answers. I should have checked in earlier.  Spent all day on this.
I'm new at Javascript and did come up with something that works on my own but it ain't
pretty. I want to learn to use Javascript correctly so I'll look over your  
responses and compare. Seems I should be able to consolidate the functions I came up 
with below or just learn from your suggestions posted here.  I guess I should become 
familiar with jquery, Ajax, etc. as I saw that used a lot in my searching for an 
answer.

<body>
<textarea id="ta" name="testinput" rows="15" cols="50"></textarea>
</body>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var i = 0;
document.getElementById('ta').innerHTML = i;
setTimeout(Test1, 3000); 

function Test1(){

  i++;
  document.getElementById('ta').innerHTML = i;
  if(i<4){ //TEXTAREA WILL STOP AT 5
    setTimeout(Test2, 3000);
  }
}

function Test2(){

  i++;
  document.getElementById('ta').innerHTML = i;
  setTimeout(Test1, 3000); 
}

</script>
```